# Change options of the current Chrome App window

Tags: google-chrome, window, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to change the minWidth of a Chrome App window who is already opened.

I've tried many things with `chrome.app.window.current()`but I can't find how to change (or even see) what is the current window's `minWidth` or `minHeight`.

Does someone know how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is being added now. You can follow the progress in the [apps-dev group discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/apps-dev/2yo7O3va4cU), as well as watching the progress of the [actual code change](https://codereview.chromium.org/25449002).